# Null space and minimization

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Let $x^*\in\text{argmin }f(x)=\text{argmin }\frac{1}{2}\|Ax-b\|^2$ where $A$ is a linear operator. Show that $\text{argmin }f=x^*+\text{Null}(A)$. For $x\in x^*+\text{Null}(A)$ we have $x\in\text{argmin }f$. How to show converse, that for any $x\in\text{argmin }f$, $x$ can be decomposed as $x=x^*+x_0,x_0\in\text{Null}(A)$?

P.S. I accidentally deleted my previous page.

Comment: Please clarify what $f$ is.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy: I'd assume that $f(x)= \frac{1}{2}\Vert Ax - b \Vert^2$.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. I made correction.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, just plug everything in.  Assume we have that

$$
\bar{x} \in \arg\min_x\{ \frac{1}{2}\|Ax-b\|^2\}
$$

and we have $\tilde{x} \in Null(A)$.  Then,

$$
\frac{1}{2}\|A(\bar{x}+\tilde{x})-b\|=\frac{1}{2}\|A\bar{x} + A\tilde{x} -b\| = \frac{1}{2} \|A\bar{x}-b\|.
$$

Here, we used the linearity of $A$ and the assumption that $\tilde{x}\in Null(A)$.  Since $\bar{x}+\tilde{x}$ yields the same objective value as $\bar{x}$, we must have that $\bar{x}+\tilde{x} \in \arg\min_x\{ \frac{1}{2}\|Ax-b\|^2\}$ for any $\tilde{x}\in Null(A)$.